# Zurb Foundation - Images with rounded corners

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've recently started using Foundation (v5), maybe I'm missing something in the documentation but I can't seem to figure out how to apply rounded corners to images. There are the `.radius` and `.round` classes, I tried using them on an img tag(also in the parent div) and it doesn't work. Bootstrap has a class ready for this, maybe in Foundation we have to code ourselves, but I'd hate to code something that already exists by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundation has a $global-radius (3px) which it applies to a lot of its classes (like thumbnails), but no it doesn't have any img-round etc...like Twitter Bootstrap does.

You will need to do your own on this [border-radius] (or if you are using Sass create your own variables).

Comment: Yes, I was about to write this. Really wired to have the class for thumbnails that has <a> and not for images itself. I see why less developers use the framework.